# Porting code from bash to Python; overriding functions

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x

I love the cool possibility in bash that allows me to override functions. To increase platform compability, I would like to port the same functionality into python, yet I do not how it can be done. These scripts demonstrates the function override in bash:

mycoolscript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

function myCoolFunc() {
    echo "Executing default implementation of myCoolFunc"
}

somevar="hello"

customfile="./${1}.sh"

if [ -e "${customfile}" ]; then
    source "${customfile}"
fi

myCoolFunc

echo "current value of 'somevar:' ${somevar}"
```

foo.sh:

```
function myCoolFunc() {
    somevar="modified!"
    echo "Executing custom implementation of myCoolFunc"
}
```

Executing the main script without any arguments:

```
$ ./mycoolscript.sh
Executing default implementation of myCoolFunc
current value of 'somevar:' hello
```

Executing the main script with 'foo' as argument:

```
$ ./mycoolscript.sh foo
Executing custom implementation of myCoolFunc
current value of 'somevar:' modified!
```

The imported script may or may not contain an override for the function, it's optional. Also, notice how the overrided function modified a variable declared in the main script.

How can I achieve the same functionality in python?

Comment: When you've been using one programming language or tool for a long time, then switch to another, there is a strong temptation to reproduce patterns from the old in the new.  Resist this.

Comment: You aren't overriding the function; you are just replacing one global definition with another.

Comment: @chepner Which, coincidentally, can be replicated in Python exactly.

Comment: What did you try before asking? (I wonder how you could have come to think that this *didn't* work when done the most obvious way, by just defining a new function under the given name).

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve something similar by overriding existing method definitions using your own implementation, for example:

```
>>> import math
>>> old_sin = math.sin
>>> def new_sin(radians):
...   print "someone called sin"
...   return old_sin(radians)
...
>>> math.sin = new_sin
>>> math.sin(10)
someone called sin
-0.5440211108893699
```

You could of course do the same with your own files and/or use it only when you receive a special argument:

**lib.py**

```
def func(a):
    return a
```

**test.py**

```
import sys
import lib

def myfunc(a):
    return a + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == 'foo':
        lib.func = myfunc
    print(lib.func(1))
```

**output**

```
>>> python test.py
1
>>> python test.py foo
2
```